# MethodInfo.Invoke Works only in Debug Mode for Prism EventAggregator

Tags: .net, silverlight, reflection, eventaggregator, prism-4

I have a extension method for Prism's EventAgregator to publish an event using reflection. The implementation is as follows:

```
MethodInfo raiseMethod = typeof(Extensions).GetMethod("Raise", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(obj.GetType());
raiseMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {eventAggregator, obj, eventType});
```

This method calls an extension method which requires a typed parameter. This code, and the eventing work fine, but only in Debug mode. When switching to a Release build the event never arrives at the subscriber.

I have tried using the optional parameter during subscription `keepSubscriberReferenceAlive` but that does not fix the problem.

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

**Update** 
I found that the issue is not releated to the above. It seems there is a filter in place which only allowed event from within the same assembly. But this really doesn't explain why the code worked while in debug mode.